# Minecraft looks like a bad texture pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Minecraft 1.12 but today the in-game textures look much lower quality than usual. I don't have any of the super secret settings turned on, and I'm unsure how to fix this and get the normal textures back.

Comment: Could you possibly give us a screenshot?

Answer (score 12):

This was an update released with April Fools day, and is only available to 1.12 clients. You can read about it here:
https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/try-new-minecraft-java-textures

Answer (score 8):

Don't worry, this got me too. I forgot it was April 1st, everything should be fine by tomorrow.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/247824)

Comment: @DJPirtu Doesn't it? Seems like it does to me. I can't speak for the accuracy of the claim that it's an April Fool's thing, and this answer could definitely be improved upon - but it *is* an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I just play on 1.14+. Those versions have much better default textures.